# Backspace and add comma before keyword in python

Tags: python, python-re

I need to backspace and add a comma right before every instance of 'https:' in a file. I believe regular expression can do this but i'm not sure how.

The line below is what I would like.

```
2021-05-11 23:39:30,https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
```

Current format is this:

```
2021-05-11 23:35:41
https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
```

Comment: What is the rule for changing the timestamp?

Comment: Strictly speaking, regular expressions themselves only do matching, they don't change anything. When you use `re.sub()`, or `sed`, that's an extra layer on top doing work with the results of a regex beyond the scope of the regex itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can't match "https" and just backspace using another method not regular expressions

Comment: That said, the bigger problem here is that this is describing the software you want built, but not your attempt to build it, or any specific issue encountered along the way.

Comment: @mkrieger1 timestamp shouldn't be touched.

Comment: From where are you getting this input data? Is it in a file?  Also if it only has these type of lines, you can just read the lines into a list and then join them using ','. Help us wth the clarification

Comment: When you say you can't use any other method -- is this a homework assignment? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) is relevant; see in particular the guidance to ask about a specific problem with your existing code, rather than about the assignment you're trying to complete.

Comment: @madil26 but it does in your example

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have made a few changes to make the file look like this.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no it's not for homework

Comment: @mkrieger1 they are 2 separate timestamps.

Comment: If it's not for homework, why do you say you "can't use any other method", if there isn't an assignment specifying it? (I'm not saying that using `re.sub()` is a bad choice, but it's unusual to have arbitrary constraints that go beyond "need to stick to standard-library functions" in real-world environments).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I meant to say I'm not opposed to another method besides re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex with pattern `r"(\n)(?=https)"`

**Ex:**

```
s = """2021-05-11 23:35:41
https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
2021-05-11 23:35:41
https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
2021-05-11 23:35:41
https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/"""

print(re.sub(r"(\n)(?=https)", r",", s))
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-11 23:35:41,https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
2021-05-11 23:35:41,https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
2021-05-11 23:35:41,https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
```

---

Without regex

```
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO("""2021-05-11 23:35:41
https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
2021-05-11 23:35:41
https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/
2021-05-11 23:35:41
https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/""")

res = []

for idx, line in enumerate(s, 1):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        res[-1] += f',{line}'
    else:
        res.append(line.strip())
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['2021-05-11 23:35:41,https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/\n',
 '2021-05-11 23:35:41,https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/\n',
 '2021-05-11 23:35:41,https://www.tiktokv.com/share/video/']
```

Comment: This works great to an extend but I have failed to mention that there is an empty line after the video link. Also, the file is 30k lines long ,so using a string input won't work.

Comment: I used the string input as a demo for the above snippet, you can use the `file` object

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just read the file, add all lines to a list. Then use `','.join()` to format and write the new string to another file.

```
file = open('test.txt')
rows = [row.strip() for row in file]
newfile = open('test2.txt','w')
newfile.write(','.join(rows))
```